# How to add thousand separator in geopandas pyplot legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I am plotting a legend of a map with geopandas and matplotlib.pyplot.
I want to see the legend values with a thousand separator, e.g. 100,000,000 at the moment it is shown like '100000000'. I would also like to be able to write the number like '100mill'. How can I achieve these two options?

```
df_test.plot(
             ax=ax,
             zorder=1,
             cax=cax,
             column='tax',
             cmap='YlOrRd',
             legend=True,
             legend_kwds={'label': '(USD)',
                          'orientation': "vertical",
                          'pad': 0.3,
                          'format': '%.0f'},
);
```

Comment: did you try to add `,` in `'%,.0f'` ? Normally `print( '{:,.0f}'.format(45000000)
)` gives me `'45,000,000'`

Comment: i'm not sure but probably `format`  may get `function's name` or `lambda` to format text - so you could create function which convert `100000000` to `100mill`.

Comment: @furas '%,.0f' unfortunately this gives an error message: ValueError: unsupported format character ',' (0x2c) at index 1

Comment: @furas: How could I try it with lambda?

Comment: first question is if it can work with functions or `lambda`  like `'format': function_name` and `def function_name(value): ... return formated_text` or `'format': lambda value: ... formated_text`

Comment: other idea: use other functions in matplotlib to add legends separatelly (after creating plot). ie. [matplotlib.pyplot.legend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no option to set a thousand separator with geopandas plot function and legend_kwds.
I solved it by retrieving the automatically generated axis labels with

```
ax.get_figure().get_axes()[1].get_yticks()
```

and then creating a custom colorbar:

```
legend_labels_auto = ax.get_figure().get_axes()[1].get_yticks()
vmin, vmax = legend_labels_auto[0], legend_labels_auto[-1]
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='YlOrRd', norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=vmin, 
vmax=vmax))
sm._A = []
cbar = fig.colorbar(sm, cax=cax, fraction=0.1, label='test')
```

In the geodataframe plot one has to add:

```
geodf.plot{
           ax=ax,
           cax=cax,
           legend=True} # legend=True even though we create our own custom legend later
```